# How to get the absolute file path of a Google drive file as a url?

Tags: html, google-chrome, google-drive-api

Is there any way to get the file path of a file in Google drive? Generally, google drive file url can be a sharing url. But what if we wanted to access the absolute file path? Something like:
drive.google.com/file/myvideo.mp4
And then I wanted to show the video file in a webpage using a video tag.

Google drive is taking too long to process a video file that I uploaded, so I cannot embed it on my website, so I thought maybe accessing the file path will do the trick :)
So how to get something like above url?

Thanks for helping.

Edit:
Found it! Now I can get the absolute file path of any file in my drive. Follow the steps:

1- Open:
https://drive.google.com/us?id=yourfileid
Where yourfileid is file id
2- load and copy the URL at the page
3- that's it, it's the absolute file path URL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [files absolute path after upload in Google drive picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832650/files-absolute-path-after-upload-in-google-drive-picker)

Answer (score 1):

to get the absolute path of a video on the google drive just send a request to the link

```
https://drive.google.com/u/1/get_video_info?docid="+IdVideo
```

the return will be a byte-by-byte file that contains all the information in the video including the absolute link it is worth remembering that the data is encoded in url right away to access it just decode another important point and that the link you obtained is only valid for the device that made the request why the link it is linked to the ip and also to the agent that sent the request for example if you sent the request with postman and try to open the link in chrome there will be an access denied error and vice versa.
Below is an example of the response provided by the request:

```
status=ok&hl=pt_BR&allow_embed=0&ps=docs&partnerid=30&autoplay=0&docid=1HCK3eleZSNQfpuZaI_oyIBQ9I_DroTq8&abd=0&public=true&el=embed&title=Jogos+Vorazes+Em+Chamas+-+ToTTi9.mp4&BASE_URL=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fu%2F0%2F&iurl=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fu%2F0%2Fvt%3Fauthuser%3D0%26id%3D1HCK3eleZSNQfpuZaI_oyIBQ9I_DroTq8%26s%3DAMedNnoAAAAAYHNJTEUxV9Q3qpFIyzfWQ9jSgXyoRJ7h&cc3_module=https%3A%2F%2Fs.ytimg.com%2Fyt%2Fswfbin%2Fsubtitles3_module.swf&ttsurl=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fu%2F0%2Ftimedtext%3Fauthuser%3D0%26id%3D1HCK3eleZSNQfpuZaI_oyIBQ9I_DroTq8%26vid%3D78edbfcf1fc76400&reportabuseurl=https%3A%2F%2Fdrive.google.com%2Fu%2F0%2Fabuse%3Fauthuser%3D0%26id%3D1HCK3eleZSNQfpuZaI_oyIBQ9I_DroTq8&token=1&plid=V0QWdNzM2hSOAQ&fmt_stream_map=18%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fr2---sn-bg0eznlz.c.drive.google.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fexpire%3D1618175340%26ei%3DLC1zYNjFDcOM8gStnI64Bg%26ip%3D45.184.131.85%26cp%3DQVRGWkJfVFNSQVhPOlp3SExoWl9oYTNKYk56Sm1iU3dGd25LakR1Y1BUM01JNmVUYW5SRDNWZjM%26id%3D78edbfcf1fc76400%26itag%3D18%26source%3Dwebdrive%26requiressl%3Dyes%26mh%3DXL%26mm%3D32%26mn%3Dsn-bg0eznlz%26ms%3Dsu%26mv%3Du%26mvi%3D2%26pl%3D24%26ttl%3Dtransient%26susc%3Ddr%26driveid%3D1HCK3eleZSNQfpuZaI_oyIBQ9I_DroTq8%26app%3Dexplorer%26mime%3Dvideo%2Fmp4%26vprv%3D1%26prv%3D1%26dur%3D8775.029%26lmt%3D1612203534601168%26mt%3D1618160459%26sparams%3Dexpire%252Cei%252Cip%252Ccp%252Cid%252Citag%252Csource%252Crequiressl%252Cttl%252Csusc%252Cdriveid%252Capp%252Cmime%252Cvprv%252Cprv%252Cdur%252Clmt%26sig%3DAOq0QJ8wRQIhAPjdubHafwixI9u_3cHc4Qt0sF8092zP3ZNSxPvqHY7nAiApe4jGKLmb4jVA4vqAGa5M-Sv2vPiwCCMFDIjzPvpq-Q%3D%3D%26lsparams%3Dmh%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cmvi%252Cpl%26lsig%3DAG3C_xAwRgIhAL9KrFxY09TeS3LW7B6wVmuM6pJTlVNC7B3uqVYHYXiuAiEAv43kEsHHcDK805VYorcU_CSm9_END9gpT_KX7QSZ9PA%3D%2C22%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fr2---sn-bg0eznlz.c.drive.google.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fexpire%3D1618175340%26ei%3DLC1zYNjFDcOM8gStnI64Bg%26ip%3D45.184.131.85%26cp%3DQVRGWkJfVFNSQVhPOlp3SExoWl9oYTNKYk56Sm1iU3dGd25LakR1Y1BUM01JNmVUYW5SRDNWZjM%26id%3D78edbfcf1fc76400%26itag%3D22%26source%3Dwebdrive%26requiressl%3Dyes%26mh%3DXL%26mm%3D32%26mn%3Dsn-bg0eznlz%26ms%3Dsu%26mv%3Du%26mvi%3D2%26pl%3D24%26ttl%3Dtransient%26susc%3Ddr%26driveid%3D1HCK3eleZSNQfpuZaI_oyIBQ9I_DroTq8%26app%3Dexplorer%26mime%3Dvideo%2Fmp4%26vprv%3D1%26prv%3D1%26dur%3D8775.029%26lmt%3D1612196404551931%26mt%3D1618160459%26sparams%3Dexpire%252Cei%252Cip%252Ccp%252Cid%252Citag%252Csource%252Crequiressl%252Cttl%252Csusc%252Cdriveid%252Capp%252Cmime%252Cvprv%252Cprv%252Cdur%252Clmt%26sig%3DAOq0QJ8wRAIgJFTtuzFA6Y8D-esOQBFfwIc0N2Sncbo32ERciZ9TaecCIGCvb44U8ejqtdUzc84GmFKT_17DpYj2iWXBROl3n5E2%26lsparams%3Dmh%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cmvi%252Cpl%26lsig%3DAG3C_xAwRQIgVeWACgdswVRbGA7KGlPCE1rbEkmbG-J7Qu_frbBTd3ECIQCvqYFUuOZ9quV33O5FsS5duvgynpNG_5IEZDm48i7Uhw%3D%3D%2C37%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fr2---sn-bg0eznlz.c.drive.google.com%2Fvideoplayback%3Fexpire%3D1618175340%26ei%3DLC1zYNjFDcOM8gStnI64Bg%26ip%3D45.184.131.85%26cp%3DQVRGWkJfVFNSQVhPOlp3SExoWl9oYTNKYk56Sm1iU3dGd25LakR1Y1BUM01JNmVUYW5SRDNWZjM%26id%3D78edbfcf1fc76400%26itag%3D37%26source%3Dwebdrive%26requiressl%3Dyes%26mh%3DXL%26mm%3D32%26mn%3Dsn-bg0eznlz%26ms%3Dsu%26mv%3Du%26mvi%3D2%26pl%3D24%26ttl%3Dtransient%26susc%3Ddr%26driveid%3D1HCK3eleZSNQfpuZaI_oyIBQ9I_DroTq8%26app%3Dexplorer%26mime%3Dvideo%2Fmp4%26vprv%3D1%26prv%3D1%26dur%3D8775.029%26lmt%3D1612265735773933%26mt%3D1618160459%26sparams%3Dexpire%252Cei%252Cip%252Ccp%252Cid%252Citag%252Csource%252Crequiressl%252Cttl%252Csusc%252Cdriveid%252Capp%252Cmime%252Cvprv%252Cprv%252Cdur%252Clmt%26sig%3DAOq0QJ8wRAIgVK9gEt4VVCfclg29yeicdxkjSLBH5GLBaGc2zZ3rFs8CIEAZ-8QHSI3r2a2JI27km7J_6lf1yAF_knmUCfboxC5G%26lsparams%3Dmh%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cmvi%252Cpl%26lsig%3DAG3C_xAwRQIhAIMFtRVlbf2oImOUp7CqF_MlH5073S-RvuJ2s3rHqwHPAiBIjnF5UtBKJ73vipMsiqERIQ0kIVFeAq_jFP93gEhnVA%3D%3D&url_encoded_fmt_stream_map=itag%3D18%26url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fr2---sn-bg0eznlz.c.drive.google.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fexpire%253D1618175340%2526ei%253DLC1zYNjFDcOM8gStnI64Bg%2526ip%253D45.184.131.85%2526cp%253DQVRGWkJfVFNSQVhPOlp3SExoWl9oYTNKYk56Sm1iU3dGd25LakR1Y1BUM01JNmVUYW5SRDNWZjM%2526id%253D78edbfcf1fc76400%2526itag%253D18%2526source%253Dwebdrive%2526requiressl%253Dyes%2526mh%253DXL%2526mm%253D32%2526mn%253Dsn-bg0eznlz%2526ms%253Dsu%2526mv%253Du%2526mvi%253D2%2526pl%253D24%2526ttl%253Dtransient%2526susc%253Ddr%2526driveid%253D1HCK3eleZSNQfpuZaI_oyIBQ9I_DroTq8%2526app%253Dexplorer%2526mime%253Dvideo%252Fmp4%2526vprv%253D1%2526prv%253D1%2526dur%253D8775.029%2526lmt%253D1612203534601168%2526mt%253D1618160459%2526sparams%253Dexpire%252Cei%252Cip%252Ccp%252Cid%252Citag%252Csource%252Crequiressl%252Cttl%252Csusc%252Cdriveid%252Capp%252Cmime%252Cvprv%252Cprv%252Cdur%252Clmt%2526sig%253DAOq0QJ8wRQIhAPjdubHafwixI9u_3cHc4Qt0sF8092zP3ZNSxPvqHY7nAiApe4jGKLmb4jVA4vqAGa5M-Sv2vPiwCCMFDIjzPvpq-Q%253D%253D%2526lsparams%253Dmh%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cmvi%252Cpl%2526lsig%253DAG3C_xAwRgIhAL9KrFxY09TeS3LW7B6wVmuM6pJTlVNC7B3uqVYHYXiuAiEAv43kEsHHcDK805VYorcU_CSm9_END9gpT_KX7QSZ9PA%253D%26type%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522avc1.42001E%252C%2Bmp4a.40.2%2522%26quality%3Dmedium%2Citag%3D22%26url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fr2---sn-bg0eznlz.c.drive.google.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fexpire%253D1618175340%2526ei%253DLC1zYNjFDcOM8gStnI64Bg%2526ip%253D45.184.131.85%2526cp%253DQVRGWkJfVFNSQVhPOlp3SExoWl9oYTNKYk56Sm1iU3dGd25LakR1Y1BUM01JNmVUYW5SRDNWZjM%2526id%253D78edbfcf1fc76400%2526itag%253D22%2526source%253Dwebdrive%2526requiressl%253Dyes%2526mh%253DXL%2526mm%253D32%2526mn%253Dsn-bg0eznlz%2526ms%253Dsu%2526mv%253Du%2526mvi%253D2%2526pl%253D24%2526ttl%253Dtransient%2526susc%253Ddr%2526driveid%253D1HCK3eleZSNQfpuZaI_oyIBQ9I_DroTq8%2526app%253Dexplorer%2526mime%253Dvideo%252Fmp4%2526vprv%253D1%2526prv%253D1%2526dur%253D8775.029%2526lmt%253D1612196404551931%2526mt%253D1618160459%2526sparams%253Dexpire%252Cei%252Cip%252Ccp%252Cid%252Citag%252Csource%252Crequiressl%252Cttl%252Csusc%252Cdriveid%252Capp%252Cmime%252Cvprv%252Cprv%252Cdur%252Clmt%2526sig%253DAOq0QJ8wRAIgJFTtuzFA6Y8D-esOQBFfwIc0N2Sncbo32ERciZ9TaecCIGCvb44U8ejqtdUzc84GmFKT_17DpYj2iWXBROl3n5E2%2526lsparams%253Dmh%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cmvi%252Cpl%2526lsig%253DAG3C_xAwRQIgVeWACgdswVRbGA7KGlPCE1rbEkmbG-J7Qu_frbBTd3ECIQCvqYFUuOZ9quV33O5FsS5duvgynpNG_5IEZDm48i7Uhw%253D%253D%26type%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522avc1.42001E%252C%2Bmp4a.40.2%2522%26quality%3Dhd720%2Citag%3D37%26url%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fr2---sn-bg0eznlz.c.drive.google.com%252Fvideoplayback%253Fexpire%253D1618175340%2526ei%253DLC1zYNjFDcOM8gStnI64Bg%2526ip%253D45.184.131.85%2526cp%253DQVRGWkJfVFNSQVhPOlp3SExoWl9oYTNKYk56Sm1iU3dGd25LakR1Y1BUM01JNmVUYW5SRDNWZjM%2526id%253D78edbfcf1fc76400%2526itag%253D37%2526source%253Dwebdrive%2526requiressl%253Dyes%2526mh%253DXL%2526mm%253D32%2526mn%253Dsn-bg0eznlz%2526ms%253Dsu%2526mv%253Du%2526mvi%253D2%2526pl%253D24%2526ttl%253Dtransient%2526susc%253Ddr%2526driveid%253D1HCK3eleZSNQfpuZaI_oyIBQ9I_DroTq8%2526app%253Dexplorer%2526mime%253Dvideo%252Fmp4%2526vprv%253D1%2526prv%253D1%2526dur%253D8775.029%2526lmt%253D1612265735773933%2526mt%253D1618160459%2526sparams%253Dexpire%252Cei%252Cip%252Ccp%252Cid%252Citag%252Csource%252Crequiressl%252Cttl%252Csusc%252Cdriveid%252Capp%252Cmime%252Cvprv%252Cprv%252Cdur%252Clmt%2526sig%253DAOq0QJ8wRAIgVK9gEt4VVCfclg29yeicdxkjSLBH5GLBaGc2zZ3rFs8CIEAZ-8QHSI3r2a2JI27km7J_6lf1yAF_knmUCfboxC5G%2526lsparams%253Dmh%252Cmm%252Cmn%252Cms%252Cmv%252Cmvi%252Cpl%2526lsig%253DAG3C_xAwRQIhAIMFtRVlbf2oImOUp7CqF_MlH5073S-RvuJ2s3rHqwHPAiBIjnF5UtBKJ73vipMsiqERIQ0kIVFeAq_jFP93gEhnVA%253D%253D%26type%3Dvideo%252Fmp4%253B%2Bcodecs%253D%2522avc1.42001E%252C%2Bmp4a.40.2%2522%26quality%3Dhd1080&timestamp=1618160940245&length_seconds=8774&fmt_list=37%2F1920x1080%2F9%2F0%2F115%2C22%2F1280x720%2F9%2F0%2F115%2C18%2F640x360%2F9%2F0%2F115
```

if you are using java script below this is a code snippet get the video link with 720 quality if available or whatever is available:

```
 async function obter_link_video(IdVideo){
      var All_Sizes_Video = {};
      var Returned = await fetch('https://drive.google.com/u/1/get_video_info?docid='+IdVideo);
      Returned = await Returned.text();
      Returned = await Returned.split("&");
      Returned.map((Value) => {
          var Result = Value.split("=");
          All_Sizes_Video[Result[0]] = Result[1];
      });
     if(All_Sizes_Video.status == "ok"){
     var size_array = [];
     var fmt_list = await decodeURIComponent(All_Sizes_Video.fmt_list);
     var fmt_list = fmt_list.split(",");
     var lenght_fmt_list = fmt_list.length-1;
     fmt_list.map((value, index) => {
         var result = value.split("/")[0];
         size_array.push(result);
         size_array.sort((a, b) => a - b);
         var length_size_array = size_array.lenght-1;
         if(index == lenght_fmt_list){
              size_array = lenght_fmt_list == 0 ?  size_array[0] : size_array[1];
         }
     });
     var map_all_links = await decodeURIComponent(All_Sizes_Video.fmt_stream_map);
     map_all_links = map_all_links.split(",");
     map_all_links.map((value) => {
         var select_size_video_by_link = value.split("|")[0] == size_array ? setlink_do_video(value.split("|")[1]) : "wrong";
         setesta_usando_link_absoluto(true);
         console.log(value.split('|')[1]);
    });
    }
  }
```

and finally the last addendum is that each ip can make a maximum of 2000 requests per day to get information about the video if this value is exceeded you will get an error.